# node.js get results of mysql outside of the function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to get "information" in this case but have to be necessarily outside of the funtion

```
  var mysql      = require('mysql');
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : '',
            database : 'db_name'
        });

connection.connect();
var insert = {
    information : something
};
var query = connection.query('insert into db.table set ?', insert, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    else {
          **getInformation = results;**

    }
    console.error(result);
});

connection.end();
```

I'm trying but doesn't work

```
console.log(getInformation)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `conneciton.end()` before the callback gets invoked.

Try the following:

```
connection.connect();
var insert = { information : 'something' };
var query = connection.query('insert into db.table set ?', insert, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }  

    console.log(result);
    connection.end();
});
```